# Binary Files and Hex Editors

Tags: matlab, binary, hex

I'm trying better understand the structure of binary files. I wrote the following code to write to unsigned 8 bit integers to a binary file in MATLAB (on Windows)

```
x = uint8(2^3); % 00010000
fid = fopen('test.bin','w');
fwrite(fid, x);
fclose(fid);
```

Then, I went to a hex editor and opened the file. As expected, I see
[image: a busy cat]

Now, I try to write a two-byte long type uint16

```
x = uint16(2^8); % 0000000100000000
fid = fopen('test.bin','w');
fwrite(fid, x,'uint16');
fclose(fid);
```

Instead of seeing 01 00 , I just see 00
[image: .]

Answer (score 0):

In General (0x10 means 10 as a hexadecimal number which is decimal 16):

```
 2^3 = 2³ = 8 = 0x08
 2^4 = 16 = 0x10
```

I don't think you do what you think you do. 2^3 is not 2*2*2 in C (and probably Matlab from your results).

**Solution:** (in C): 2<<3 = 2 * (2*2*2) = 10000 = 16 = 0x10

**Explanation:**

In C (not sure about Matlab):

2<<3 means: 10 << 000 = 10000 = 16 = 0x10.

Each <<1 means "add one zero behind the binary number", which is equavivalent to multiply by 2 ( *2). This works in the other direction too >>1 is the same as dividing by 2 ( /2).

2^3 means not 2³ (Exponent) but BINARY AND.

You do:

```
2 is binary 10
3 is binary 11
```

11&10 = 10

```
10
11
--
10
```

One under One means One, Zero under One means 0. One and One is One. Zero and One is Zero. Or more formal: (true ^ false) = false.

This is probably why 2^8 doesn't work.

0010 (2) & 1000 (8) = 0000

```
 0010
 1000
 ----
 0000
```

There is no 1 under a 1, so it is all 0.

Comment: But, in MATLAB, 2^3 = 8.

Comment: This is strange, you should see in the hexeditor 0x08 instead of 0x10 for an 8. Maybe the problem is, that the  value unsigned, sometimes funny things happens to the bits, if the value is unsigned.

Comment: Oh, yes you're correct. My hex editor (Notepad++) plugin was caching and messing up with previous values of the file